# Any way to stop SwiftUI Text showing an ellipse?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a Text view that dynamically shows different text depending on the value of a state variable. As I cycle through the values, if the new text is longer than the old text, I momentarily get an ellipse (...) before the new text is shown. The code that experiences this looks like:

```
Text(flashModeDescription(flashMode: appSettings.flashMode))
                        .font(.body).foregroundColor(.white)
                        .opacity(flashModeDescVisible ? 1: 0)
                        .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.25))
```

The Text view is the last item in an HStack.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Can you show how it looks for you in action?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to animation defined, so the following could fix

```
Text(flashModeDescription(flashMode: appSettings.flashMode))
                        .font(.body).foregroundColor(.white)
                        .animation(nil)                        // << here !!
                        .opacity(flashModeDescVisible ? 1: 0)
                        .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.25))
```

so animation would affect only opacity

Comment: Wow! Fantastic, this fixed it. I did not realise that you could turn off the animation at the various levels. Brilliant answer.